# Single Embedding Layer for Multiple Categorical columns?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, word-embeddings

I have 100 binary categorical columns to train a neural network model. Each row will be a vector-like [1,1,0,...1] of length 100. I fed this vector to a neural network for a classification problem and found its MRR score. Then I experimented by using an Embedding Layer. I did it by first converting each vector to tokens (Ex: [1,0,...] = 23, where 23 is the token) and providing it to the same neural network. I experimented with different embedding sizes, but the performance I get from using the embedding layer is lower than I got by feeding the raw muti-hot vector to a neural network.

Why is this happening? If I set the embedding dimension to a larger size (>100), will it help?

Comment: I can’t see why, a priori, the original idea (which you call “converting to tokens”)  would help. You erase the relatedness of individual components of the binary vector, then force the model to discover this on its own while learning everything else too. Even if embedding the binary vectors makes sense, this technique doesn’t. Increasing the dimensionality may help, only insomuch as you have more parameters.

Comment: The reason why I want to use embedding is to capture the latent meaning of the item. Each row represents the properties of an item and I thought using an embedding would capture some higher dimensional meaning. As you said I erase the relatedness while doing it, which doesn't sound like a great idea. Thanks

Comment: @Sanjay Rather than "capture some higher dimensional meaning", you had actually reduced the dimensionality from 100 down to 1.